# What is a good expression to refer to conversations around the coffee machine?

Tags: expressions, synonyms

Im not sure what's the most colloquial way to talk about those times when with colleagues you debate politics. Is it "office kitchen" talks ? Coffee machine talks ?

Comment: I’ve always heard that referred to as “water cooler conversation”

Comment: Are you looking for Water Cooler talk?

Comment: coffee klatch, scuttle butt (although originally described gossip around a water dispenser)

Comment: I've generally heard it as "talk around the coffee machine", "coffee machine scuttlebutt", or some such.  As suggested below, though, "water cooler talk" or "water cooler conversation" is a more "traditional" and generic way of putting it, even though people don't hang around the water cooler much anymore.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Water cooler chatter**

"[Water cooler talk](http://esl-bits.net/idioms/id670.htm)" sounds a bit flat and is a silly cliche.

Comment: And "water cooler chatter" somehow isn't because one word is changed? The key words in this phrase are "water cooler". *That's* the part that makes it sound flat and cliched.

Comment: "word around the water cooler",  "water cooler talk",  "water cooler chat", "water cooler conversation", "water cooler [insert_your_word]" all convey the same concept.

Comment: Sounding like a cliche is proof that it's widely recognized and well-known.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, that's easy..."coffee talk" a la [SNL](https://www.nbc.com/saturday-night-live/video/coffee-talk/n10117?snl=1).